# Use coalesce in json set returning function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a data stored in a little weird way, but I have to work on this. The following sample represents its structure:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rAALhAatyedGgXK5LxvLeG/3

```
create table tickets
(ticket_id integer,
 properties text);

 insert into tickets
 values
 (123,'[{"details":[
{"amount":"5","price":150},
{"amount":"2","price":200}]}]'),

(124,'[{"details":[
{"price":430}
]}]'),

(125,'[{"details":[] }]');
```

I managed to extract needed data, probably not in the most elegant way but output is **ALMOST** what I needed.

```
SELECT 
ticket_id,
REPLACE((json_array_elements(json_array_elements(properties::json)->'details')->'amount')::TEXT, '"','')::int as amount,
((json_array_elements(json_array_elements(properties::json)->'details')->'price')::text)::int AS price
FROM tickets

ticket_id   amount  price
123         5       150
123         2       200
124         null    430
```

The missing record is `ticket 125` with `null` in both `amount` and `price` column. Why it's gone from results if both price and amount are missing but gives null if just one of them is missing?

@edit I found the reason, if the array details is empty it doesn't contain json no more. But still idk how to overcome it.

Ideally I would like to use `coalesce` and put there `1` if it's null but it gives an

```
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in COALESCE
```

How can I work around it?

Comment: The outer array in the "JSON" column seems rather pointless. And why are you using the `text` type instead of `jsonb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set returning functions should be used in the FROM clause.

To include the row with id = 125 (with the empty array) you need to use an outer join against the `jsonb_array_elements()` function so that rows where the result of that is empty are included.

```
SELECT ticket_id, 
       (d.detail ->> 'price')::int as price,
       (d.detail ->> 'amount')::int as amount
FROM tickets
  left join jsonb_array_elements( ((properties::Jsonb) -> 0) -> 'details' ) as d(detail) on true
```

[Online example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tQs7HQdCV7GsSctLvMR2o2/1)

Comment: Wow... I'm just speechless how you simplified the whole query, you're pure genius :) Thank you so much